# Conversion of Powermockito Junit Tests to MockitoRunner

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I would just like to ask if there's an easy way or manageable way to convert an existing Junit running on Power Mockito to Mockito Runner? The Powermockito doesn't seem to be supported for JDK 17 and the work around I found (--ad-opens java.base/java.lang = ALL -UNNAMED) doesn't really work well. I'm currently using Visual Studio Code for my environment (was the required IDE to use).

I have been trying to do some research as I'm basically a bean sprout level when it comes to this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.